# ReportDiagnostic on Partial Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I am modifying the default analyzer project that comes from the code analyzer template to try and get it to report at all of the declarations for a partial class.

I have modified the code to:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.NamedType);
}

private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    var namedTypeSymbol = (INamedTypeSymbol)context.Symbol;

    // Find just those named type symbols with names containing lowercase letters.
    if (namedTypeSymbol.Name.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsLower))
    {
        foreach (var location in namedTypeSymbol.Locations)
        {
            // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, location, namedTypeSymbol.Name);
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
}
```

In two separate files, I have partial classes like this:

```
// File1.cs
partial class Foo
{
    public string BarString;
}

// File2.cs
partial class Foo
{
    public string FooBarString;
}
```

I put breakpoints on the ReportDiagnostic and am seeing it called for each location, but within Visual Studio it only reports diagnostics within a single file.

If I put multiple implementations of `Foo` in a single file (and it happens to be reporting on that files declaration) then I will see both diagnostics reported.

Am I misunderstanding how diagnostics are supposed to be reported or is this a bug?  If it is a bug, is it a Roslyn problem or is it a problem with Visual Studio's consumption of Roslyn?

Comment: Do you have both files open in the IDE?

Comment: Yes, both files are open.

Comment: I can reproduce this. It feels like a bug to me. If you haven't already I'd recommend opening an issue for this at: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the V1 implementation of the Visual Studio diagnostic service.

There is an issue in the Roslyn repository to track this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3748#issuecomment-117231706

From the response in the Github issue:

> This is a known issue in the v1 implementation of the Visual Studio
>   IDE's diagnostic service. It currently doesn't handle analyzer
>   reporting diagnostics outside the document being analyzed. So, if
>   File1.cs has the primary definition of `Foo` for which `AnalyzeSymbol` was
>   invoked, then the diagnostic service only retains diagnostics reported
>   by the analyzer within this file.